Jetpack Compose ModalNavigationDrawer with SwipeToDismissBox disables the gesture for opening nav drawer
Is it possible to have a LazyColumn with a SwipeToDismissBox also work correctly within a ModalNavigationDrawer?
I have a basic composable with a ModalNavigationDrawer that has a LazyColumn within it.
Within my LazyColumn I have my SwipeToDismissBox with the "enableDismissFromStartToEnd" set to false and within that i have my ListItem.
I was hoping that disabling the "enableDismissFromStartToEnd" would allow for the swipe gesture to still work for my NavigationDrawer but that is not the case.
I have had a look around at other android apps and can see that Gmail works in exactly the way that i would expect this to work where you can swipe on the item to delete but also swipe from the very far edge to open the drawer.

Found an issue on the bug tracker that describes this issue exactly.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/167408603
I have recently commented on it and they have since reopened the issue.
